# Calling synchronized method from ExecutorService not working properly

Tags: java, spring, rest, elasticsearch, synchronized

I have a REST API with some synchronized tasks that give me errors. I'll try to explain the idea.

Suppose I have the following code in my Controller class:

```
@Qualifier("serviceA")
@Autowired
private UpdateService updateServiceA; // connected to host A

@Qualifier("serviceB")
@Autowired
private UpdateService updateServiceB; // connected to host B

@Autowired
private ExecutorService myExecutorService;

// one of my endpoints calls update method below

public void update(Object x) {
   myExecutorService.submit(() -> {
      updateServiceA.remove(x); // remove x on host A
      updateServiceB.remove(x); // remove x on host B
   }
}
```

And in `UpdateServiceImpl` class I have the following:

```
public class UpdateServiceImpl implements UpdateService {

   public synchronized void remove(Object x) {
     // 1. find x
     // 2. if x exists, remove it
     // Response response = elasticSearch.performRequest(...)
   }

}
```

And the beans are configured in a configuration class as follows:

```
@Bean
public ExecutorService executorService() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1);
}

@Qualifier("serviceA")
@Bean
public UpdateService getUpdateService() {
    return new UpdateServiceImpl();
}

@Qualifier("serviceB")
@Bean
public UpdateService getUpdateService() {
    return new UpdateServiceImpl();
}
```

The backend is ElasticSearch. Remove method is just perfoming a delete operation.

Once in a while I see in my logs that an entry is found but when it tries to remove it, it does not exist anymore. I get the feeling that another thread (?) already removed the object in the meantime. I don't understand why the `synchronized` method is not working properly.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Very hard to tell from the code you posted. It should work as expect.

Comment: Perhaps concurrent requests are processed on different nodes of a cluster?

Comment: How is UpdateServiceImpl instantiated? If you have multiple instances running on different threads, then a synchronized method won't help you.

Comment: The "synchronized" keyword cannot prevent duplicate invocation. Please consider adding some logs at 'remove' and 'update' to check for any duplicate invocation.

Comment: Do you have any `wait()/notify()` calls in `remove()` method?

Comment: I have updated the question a bit. We use Elasticsearch as backend. No `wait()/notify()` anywhere.

Comment: So you use remote ElasticSearch application. And your lock doesn't actually lock that ElasticSearch instance. So everybody can manually or programmatically remove that object between your code calls `find()` and `remove`.